# Connecting tables when querying in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 3 tables: `tco_articles`, `tco_module_eostext` and `tco_articles_modules`. My `tco_articles` has unique `id` key. One for each article. My `tco_module_eostext` has unique `instance_id` that belongs to each article. 
My `tco_articles_modules` contains all `article_id`s, but have 9 times as much `instance_id`s that are used in other tables.

[image]

So I can have `article_id` with `instance_id` that when you query in the `tco_module_eostext` will return empty.

I'd like to make a query that will return correct body text for the correct article.

So far I have:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = array();

$ids = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT instance_id, article_id FROM tco_articles_modules', ARRAY_A);
```

This returns array with all the instances and ids like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [instance_id] => 928615
            [article_id] => 129396
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [instance_id] => 928616
            [article_id] => 129396
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [instance_id] => 928617
            [article_id] => 129396
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [instance_id] => 928618
            [article_id] => 129396
        )
```

You can see that the `article_id`s are the same but `instance_id`. When you put

```
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT body FROM tco_module_eostext WHERE instance_id=928617 ', ARRAY_A);
```

You may get empty, but for

```
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT body FROM tco_module_eostext WHERE instance_id=928618 ', ARRAY_A);
```

You could have some body text.

This is my problem. I need to go through all of them and filter out the not empty ones and assign them correct article. I managed to output the articles

```
foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $instance_ID = $value['instance_id'];
    $article_ID = $value['article_id'];

    $article_out = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM tco_articles WHERE id='.$article_ID.' ', ARRAY_A);
    $posts[$article_ID] = $article_out[0];

}
```

Which returns something like:

```
Array
(
    [129396] => Array
        (
            [id] => 129396
            [headline] => Bla bla bla title
            [intro] => This is cool article intro
            [needs_review] => 0
            [published] => 2014-12-16 09:17:00
            [unpublished] => 
            [hidden] => 0
            [no_single_page] => 0
            [permalink] => link-perma-link-here
            [internal_slug] => 
            [type_id] => 3
            [thread_id] => 0
            [news_id] => 0
            [header_game_id] => 0
            [puff_hh_id] => 0
            [puff_title] => 
            [hdrcol_id] => 900
            [review_queued] => 
            [lock_timeout] => 0
            [created] => 2014-12-16 09:17:00
            [updated] => 2015-01-16 13:51:30
            [created_by] => 84142
            [updated_by] => 84142
        )
    ...
```

Now I'd like to append the `body` text from the `tco_module_eostext` table.

Is there a query I can use to do this automatically or to do this one at the time and then append to the `$posts` array?

The foreach method of querying is kinda slow when you have 180000+ posts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, `tco_module_eostext` can have multiple `body` text as you can have multiple `instance_id` related. If there is multiple, which one you want to get? Latest one (by instance_id DESC) ?

Comment: For each `instance_id` in the `tco_module_eostext` table there is a `body` text attached (unique for each id). But I don't have a way of finding out to which article this text belongs to, unless I go through `tco_articles_modules`, which holds 9 `instance_id`s for 1 `article_id`. Only one from this 9 is the right one, the rest are empty. `article_id` is the same as the `id` in the `tco_articles` table.

Comment: So, you are sure, that there will be always only one row in `tco_module_eostext`  for (one of) each 9 `instance_ids` ?

Comment: Yeah, I've tested it and from what I've saw only one in nine was always present. I mean I didn't check every one out of 180000 :D So I'd say I'm like 98% sure. I didn't build the database, I'm just migrating it to wp...

Comment: Check my answer and let me know which one works for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that there is always only one row in `tco_module_eostext` against each `article_id`, you can use `JOIN` (inner join), which will only show one row for each `article_id`.

```
SELECT a.*, t.body
FROM tco_articles a
JOIN tco_articles_modules m ON m.article_id = a.id
JOIN tco_module_eostext t ON m.instance_id = t.instance_id
//WHERE .....
```

But, this will not show any row of some articles if there is no entry in other two tables for that `article_id`. But there is still way to solve this. We can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then make sure we only make the join if there is any row in `tco_module_eostext` for any `instace_id`. This will make sure you get at least the article info from `tco_articles` table when there is no data in other tables.

```
SELECT a.*, t.body
FROM tco_articles a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tco_articles_modules m ON m.article_id = a.id AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL FROM tco_module_eostext WHERE instance_id = m.instance_id )
LEFT OUTER JOIN tco_module_eostext t ON m.instance_id = t.instance_id
//WHERE .....
```

Comment: This did the trick so far as I can see. You had one small error in the first part: `JOIN tco_articles_modules m ON m.article_id = a.id` because the primary key in the articles table is just `id`. But it returned the array with the body text appended. Thanks! This will help me a lot! :)

Comment: I'll probably need to modify this a bit, to include the rest of my db but at least now I know how to start :) And no foreach helps a lot! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a query with join?

**Not tested!:**

```
SELECT
    article.*,
    text.body as bodytext
FROM
    tco_articles_modules AS modules LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tco_module_eostext AS text ON
        modules.instance_id = text.instance_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tco_articles AS article ON
        article.id = modules.article_id
```

it should get all articles with the assigned `article_id` from `tco_articles_modules`

Have a look at OUTER Join - you may want to replace this with an INNER JOIN for faster Queries. Also you ma want an WHERE condition for filtering in the query. Watch also out for the right indexing in mysql table - each joining column should be indexed - this will get much more faster results.

Comment: Noting that, there may be duplication of data!

Comment: I'll give this a go and see what comes out :)

Comment: Yaeh there could be duplication of data as well. If there are you have to group them via either the ON statement or globaly in the GROUP BY statment. If you could provide a dump of your data i could get an working query for you.

Comment: The data is from a live site, I'm not sure that the client would allow his data to be publicly available :\ Sorry